# Plot vector field in matlab

Tags: matlab, vector, electromagnetism

I have the function of an electric dipole expressed in cartesian coordinates and I want to create the vector field using Matlab .

The function is 
   $$E_z= \frac{p}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \cdot \left(\frac{3z^2}{r^5}- \frac{1}{r^3}\right) $$ and $$E_x=\frac{p}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \frac{3xz}{r^5}\;. $$ .

The code I've come up with is :

```
clear;
clc;
p = 1;
e = 8.85*10^(-12);
x  =linspace(-5 , 5, 50);
z = linspace(-5 , 5 ,50);
[X, Z ] = meshgrid(x,z );
R=sqrt(X.^2+Z.^2) ; 
EX =( p .* 3 .* X .* Z )./ (4.*pi.*e ./ R.^5);
EZ = p./( 4 .* pi .* e ) .* ( 3.* Z.^2 ./R.^5 -1./ R.^3);
quiver ( X , Z , EX , EZ ) ;
```

But it doesn't give me the output I want which looks like this 
[image]

Does anyone have any ideas? I would be grateful!

Answer (score 2):

For plotting, it is easier in my opinion to not use meshgrid if you want to scale the arrows. You have a vector field $(E_X, E_Z)$ and you can simply normalize it like in the code below:

```
clear;
clc;
p = 1;
e = 8.85*10^(-12);
x  =linspace(-5 , 5, 20);
z = linspace(-5 , 5 ,20);

for i = 1:length(x)
    for k = 1:length(z)
        R=sqrt(x(i)^2 + z(k)^2) ; 
        EX =( p * 3 * x(i) * z(k) ) / (4 * pi * e / R^5);
        EZ = p / ( 4 * pi * e ) * ( 3 * z(k)^2 / R^5 - 1 / R^3);
        ex(i, k) = EX / sqrt(EX^2 + EZ^2);
        ez(i, k) = EZ / sqrt(EX^2 + EZ^2);
    end
end
scaleFactor = 0.5; 
quiver ( x , z , ex , ez, scaleFactor, 'LineWidth', 2); 
axis([-5 5 -5 5])
```

To make the arrows look nicer, you can play with Matlab's plotting manipulators.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it.  Normalize everything so the arrows are same size, and remove NaN's at the origin.

```
p = 1;
eps0 = 8.854e-12;

x = linspace(-5,5,20);
z = x;

[xx,zz] = meshgrid(x,z);

rr = sqrt(xx.^2 + zz.^2);

ex = p/(4*pi*eps0) .* (3.*xx.*zz)./(rr.^5);
ez = p/(4*pi*eps0) .* (3.*zz.^2./rr.^5 - 1./rr.^3);

E = sqrt(ex.^2 + ez.^2);
E(isnan(E)) = max(E(:));

figure;
    quiver(x,z,ex./E,ez./E)
```